# angular version upgrade 5.6 to 6.0 ( rxjs 6.0)

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Having an application which runs on angular5.6 version , but some reason want to upgrade to 6x version . Is there a migration script ? or something can help without code / reference changes .. Thanks in advance !

```
   Created a sample app , its showing below reference is missing 

   import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to force the version:

```
npm install -g rxjs@6.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check https://update.angular.io

You can select from which and to which version you want to upgrade and they'll provide the commands you'll need to execute.